# React routing help routing not actually jumping to the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I am very new to React and react routing so forgive me if this is simple. I have seen similar questions asked but not quite what I was looking for or I didnt understand it enough to figure it out.

**Question:** How do I get routing to jump to the page? It changes in the URL but seemingly no change. (localhost:8080/#/listings?_k=26kljm) is the same as localhost:8080/

Anyway here is what I have

### main.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import Listing from "./components/pages/Listings";
import NoMatch from "./components/partials/NoMatch";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="/listings" name="listings" component={Listing}></Route>
   </Route>
 </Router>,
app);
```

### Layout.js

```
import React from "react";

import Footer from "./partials/Footer";
import Body from "./pages/Index";
import Header from "./partials/Header";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Header/>
       <Body />
       <Footer />
     </div>
   );
  }
}
```

### Header.js

This one is long so ill spare you but you should know there is a link

```
<Link to="/listings">Listings</Link>
```

And finally

### Listings.js

```
import React from "react";

import Header from "../partials/Header";
import Footer from "../partials/Footer";

export default class Listings extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1>THIS SHOULD BE HERE</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
      );
   }
 }
```

I feel like I am missing something small or I dont have a good grasp on components.

To Note: I just noticed in the source the `Link` created an href like this
    Listings

Why is the extra hash there!?
I get a `Cannot GET /listings` if I go directly to `localhost:8080/listings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with how I was understanding components.
The key here is `{this.props.children}`

By changing Layout.js too:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        {this.props.children}
       <Footer />
     </div>
   );
 }
```

}

### main.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Index}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="/listings" name="listings" component={Listing}></Route>
   </Route>
</Router>,
app);
```

The makes routing work correctly

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I cannot find any mistake in your code. But I would recommend you to check out the react router examples which will fit perfect to your case: 
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Just clone this repo, run `npm install` and `npm start`. Then you can browse through the examples within the URL [http:localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080). 
When you take a look at the ["Active Links" example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/active-links), you will notice that it shows exactly what you want (except HashHistory, but you can add this manually without much work).

Hope this helps.

Many greetings